# Adding subclass inheritance outside a class when instantiating

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance, subclass

I want to add the inheritance of one or more classes to another class depending on specific requirements; rather than creating multiple subclasses by hand, I want to be able to custom build them on the fly.

For example, the primary class, that would inherit from the others, is Sandwich:

```
class Sandwich(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sandwich, self).__init__()
        self.bread = "brown"
        self.amount = 2
```

The base classes would be:

```
class Meat(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Meat, self).__init__()
        self.ham = False
        self.chicken = False
        self.beef = False

class Vegetables(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Vegetables, self).__init__()
        self.lettuce = False
        self.onion = False

class Vegan(Vegetables):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Vegetables, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.vegan_cheese = False
```

I want to create instances of these classes like this:

```
meat_sandwich = Sandwich(Meat)
veg_sandwich = Sandwich(Vegetables)
meat_and_veg_sandwich = Sandwich(Meat, Vegetables)
vegan_sandwich = Sandwich(Vegan)
```

I want to be able to access all variables and methods from these classes, and from the main class.

```
print(meat_sandwich.bread)
meat_sandwich.ham = True
```

I have found that you can assign a new class using `__new__`, however I have only succeeded in replacing the main class, and not setting up multiple inheritance / subclassing:

```
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Set to assign any given subclass """
        subcls = [i for i in args if isinstance(i, type)]

        if subcls:
            return super(Sandwich, cls).__new__(*subcls)

        else:
            return superSandwich, cls).__new__(cls)
```

Comment: Nothing inherits from your base class. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I guess base class was the wrong terminology. Root class? What I want is for the Sandwich class to inherit from any and all of the other classes, as and when needed depending on the coding requirements.  I am building a system of template classes which will contain various variable naming syntax that I want the user to have access to, but only with specific models.  Some models may contain one template of vars, whereas others may have a couple.

Comment: Surely this would be better suited with composition over inheritance. Allow a Snadwich to contain a list of ingredients and create helpers to determine attributes about the makeup of a given instance.

Comment: *What I want is for the Sandwich class to inherit from any and all of the other classes* while it's possible, it doesn't make sense.  `Meat` should be a "meat sandwich" right? than it should inherit from `Sandwich`, not the other way around.

Comment: I've amended the description. I was mixing up the name terminologies, I think.

Comment: Inheritance is probably not the best approach here, but it's hard to say more with just a toy example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the results I was after, although I appreciate that I did not explain the problem very well, and suspect this might be something of a hack.

At any rate, I hope this helps illustrate what it was I was trying to achieve, and I would be interested in hearing alternate approaches to this solution.

```
meat_sandwich = type('meatSandwich_type', (Sandwich, Meat), dict())()
veg_sandwich = type('vegSandwich_type', (Sandwich, Vegetables), dict())()
meat_and_veg_sandwich = type('meatAndVegSandwich_type', (Sandwich, Meat, Vegetables), dict())()
vegan_sandwich = type('meatAndVegSandwich_type', (Sandwich, Vegan), dict())()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inheritance in my opinion it makes more sense to use composition here.

This will simplify the construction of the objects, and make it more flexible to change (such as adding new ingredients).

For example, each set of ingredient types could be a separate `Enum`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Bread(Enum):
    WHITE = "white"
    WHOLE_WHEAT = "whole wheat"
    BROWN = "brown"

class Meat(Enum):
    HAM = "ham"
    CHICKEN = "chicken"
    BEEF = "beef"

class Vegetable(Enum):
    LETTUCE = "lettuce"
    ONION = "onion"

class Vegan(Enum):
    CHEESE = "vegan_cheese"
```

Now when defining the sandwich class you could do something like this:

```
class Sandwich:
    def __init__(self, bread, ingredients=None):
        self.bread = bread
        self.ingredients = ingredients or []
```

To ask something like (as done in your example) if the sandwich contains ham, you could do:

```
>>> meat_sandwich = Sandwich(Bread.WHITE, [Meat.HAM])
>>> Meat.HAM in meat_sandwich.ingredients
True
```

To ask if the sandwich contains no meat, you could do:

```
>>> veg_sandwich = Sandwich(Bread.BROWN, [Vegetable.LETTUCE])
>>> all(not isinstance(i, Meat) for i in veg_sandwich.ingredients)
True
```